# Asp.NET Repeater Control (like a chat )

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I want to create a "What are you thinking" like Facebook option. However, I couldn't write a comment under the title which the user wrote before. Maybe I should use 2 repeaters? I have tried the following code but it does not solve my problem:

```
TextBox txtCevap = e.Item.FindControl("txtCevap") as TextBox;
HiddenField hf = e.Item.FindControl("hfYorumID") as HiddenField;
int id = Convert.ToInt32(hf.Value);
object sessionToString = Session["KullaniciID"];

SqlCommand sqlSelect = new SqlCommand("sp_cevapEkle", conn);
sqlSelect.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

sqlSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("YorumID", id);
sqlSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KullaniciID", Convert.ToInt32(sessionToString));
sqlSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cevap", txtCevap.Text.ToString());
sqlSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tarih", DateTime.Now);
if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
conn.Open();
sqlSelect.ExecuteNonQuery();
txtCevap.Text = "";

rptNeDusunuyorsun.DataBind();
```

Comment: Could you provide some html with that code?  Supplying C# which calls a stored procedure and sets the results onto a repeater isn't really telling us anything...

...That said, it doesn't appear you actually run a query to get the comments back and set them on the repeater - unless `rptNeDusunuyorsun`'s data source is already bound to the query...

Comment: For example when you write a comments on Facebook your friend want to answer them. And i can code the first comment but my friend couldn't answer it. I use one repeater to see my comments. When i answer it i couldn't insert the new comments under the first comment. My code doesn't work. I want to do a chat program on asp.net maybe we can consider like this. i should get first comment id. i put it hiddenfield but the other code is not work which you see below. And html code is like this :